# Is there an equivalent of EOPAGE in .net?

Tags: php, .net

Just wondering if there's any .net equivalent of the EOPAGE from PHP?
For clarity of my question here's an example of typical usage of EOPAGE in php:

```
echo EOPAGE >>>
<div class="someclass" id="someid">EOPAGE rocks!</div>
<div>...
EOPAGE;
```

Basically I am looking to loop through an array and format the output without having to escape and piece up substrings in .net.

Thx in advance!

P.S.: I am aware of similar .net controls such as repeater which pretty much serve the same end goal with the implementation of templates & datasources but I just would like some plain fuss-free options that are applicable in a non-page context such as where a response handler is used.

Comment: That's called  [`Heredoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a string in C# with line breaks you can use `@`:

```
string s=@"ahsj skksjjsnnslskk
jjjjdjjasd
adsadassa
asdasdsad
asdsgdgdsg";
```

With tis syntax you can still write double quotes inside the string by just duplicate the sign: `""` to represent `"`.

Comment: thx for that but i would like to use more than line breaks especially doulbe quotes

Comment: @user1611132 you can use double quotes by writing twice "" = "

Comment: thx again. hate to be a pain but what about the variables? is String.Format with variables arranged in an array the only way to go?